# Activerecord: Cannot get :through => to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on a project in which people organize gaming sessions. The (abridged) Model is as follows.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy      #events organized by user
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :events
  belongs_to :users
end
```

In this way, when I use `@user.events` I get, as expected, a list of the event the user organizes.

But I wanted a list of the events that the User has a reservation to, (using something like `@user.reserved_events`, so I added this to the User model:

```
has_many :reserved_events, :class_name => 'Event',:through => reservations
```

This broke everything, and I got a mysterious

```
undefined local variable or method `reservations' for #<Class:0x00000003681048>
```

***EDIT***

Thanks to Christopher Manning, I changed `reservations` to `:reservations`, thus eliminating the trivial error. However, if I now try to use `@user.reserved_events` o `@user.reservations.count`, i get

```
Could not find the source association(s) :reserved_event or :reserved_events in model Reservation. Try 'has_many :reserved_events, :through => :reservations, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :events or :users?
```

Complying to the request leads me nowhere: if I use `:source => :users`, I get

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: reservations.users_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" INNER JOIN "reservations" ON "events"."id" = "reservations"."users_id" WHERE "reservations"."user_id" = 1
```

using `:source => :events` makes it balk at a different missing column

My temporary solution is to use direct SQL:

`@reserved_events = Event.find_by_sql("select events.* from events,reservations where events.id=reservations.event_id AND reservations.user_id="+@user.id.to_s)`

Better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change `reservations` to `:reservations` in the line

```
has_many :reserved_events, :class_name => 'Event',:through => reservations
```

to fix the undefined local variable or method error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations, :through => :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :events
end
```

This should allow you to say:

```
@user.reservations
```

Event should have a user_id field. Reservation should have an event_id field. Let me know what issues you get with this.

Comment: Well, it works, sort of, but it does not solve my problems. I found out a "Just works" solution for now, which is a plain SQL query: ` `@reserved_events = Event.find_by_sql("select events.* from events,reservations where events.id=reservations.event_id AND reservations.user_id="+@user.id.to_s)`. This not very "Raily", but it's a one-liner and as of now it fits the bill.
`